# How to disable Urls appearing in browser history - Yii2

Tags: gridview, yii2, pushstate, pjax

I am using **advanced template** of **Yii 2.0**. I am using **pjax** to show data in **grid view** which is set for *auto refreshing*. I am following [this](http://blog.neattutorials.com/examples/pjax/web/site/auto-refresh) link to set my grid view auto refresh.

The problem is: this is forcing the same Url appearing in the browser's history(since anchor tag is calling same action again & again to get updated data) which I don't want to appear in history.

I tried a lot to find the solution but found nothing.
I need help solving the issue. I know there's a lot of smart coders out here who wants to do something new. Help me doing this.
Thanks in advance!!

I tried setting `'enablePushState' => false` but still the Url appears in history.

Comment: have you tried setting `enableReplaceState` to `true` also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading Yii documentation carefully and following [topher's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/428543/topher) comment, I tried setting `['enablePushState'=>flase, 'enableReplaceState=>true]`

This worked but causing whole page(view) auto refresh sometimes.
But setting only `['enableReplaceState=>true]` worked for me.

Hope this helps someone in future.